# Branching process: show $P(Z_m>k|Z_n=0) \le (G_n(0))^k, m<n,k\ge 0$

Tags: probability

Let $(Z_n)_{n \ge 0}$ be a branching process with generating function $G_n(s)=E(s^{Z_n})$.
Let $m<n$, show that $P(Z_m>k|Z_n=0) \le (G_n(0))^k, k \ge 0$.

I know that the event $\{Z_n=0\}_{n \ge 0}$ are nested upward, that is $\{Z_i=0\}\subseteq\{Z_j=0\}$ whenever $i <j$, and that $P(Z_n=0)=G_n(0)$. I guess I need to decompose $\{Z_m>k|Z_n=0\}$ into other events, but I don't find a decomposition that gives the result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let us first assume that $Z_0=1$ almost surely and let us estimate
$$
\mathrm P(Z_m>k, Z_n=0)=\mathrm E(\mathrm P(Z_n=0\mid Z_m);Z_m>k).
$$
For each integer $i$, $\mathrm P(Z_n=0\mid Z_m=i)=G_{n-m}(0)^i$ hence
$$
\mathrm P(Z_m>k, Z_n=0)=\mathrm E(G_{n-m}(0)^{Z_m};Z_m>k)\leqslant G_{n-m}(0)^{k+1},
$$
and
$$
\mathrm P(Z_m>k\mid Z_n=0)\leqslant\frac{G_{n-m}(0)^{k+1}}{\mathrm P(Z_n=0)}=G_{n-m}(0)^{k}\frac{G_{n-m}(0)}{G_n(0)},
$$
Now the sequence $(G_k(0))_k$ is nondecreasing hence $G_{n-m}(0)\leqslant G_n(0)$ and $G_{n-m}(0)^{k}\leqslant G_{n}(0)^{k}$. This proves the result when $Z_0=1$ almost surely.

If $Z_0=i$ almost surely, with $i\geqslant1$, $G_j(s)=H_j(s)^i$ where $H_j(s)=\mathrm E(s^{Z_j}\mid Z_0=1)$ and $\mathrm P(Z_n=0)=H_n(0)^i$, hence
the same computations yield
$$
\mathrm P(Z_m>k\mid Z_n=0)\leqslant\frac{H_{n-m}(0)^{k+1}}{H_n(0)^i}\leqslant H_{n}(0)^{k+1-i},
$$
which cannot be bounded uniformly over $i$. Thus the result probably does not hold for every initial population.

**Edit** One can remove the word *probably* in the last sentence above. To prove this, assume that the result proposed by the OP holds for every starting population $Z_0$. Whether $G_k$ means $G_k(s)=\mathrm E(s^{Z_k}\mid Z_0=i)$ or $G_k(s)=\mathrm E(s^{Z_k}\mid Z_0=1)$, $G_k(0)\le \mathrm P_1(Z_k=0)=q_k$ where the subscript $1$ indicates that $Z_0=1$. Hence we are asked to prove for example that, for every $k$ and $t$,
$$
\mathrm P_{tk}(Z_1>k\mid Z_n=0)\leqslant q_n^k,
$$
where the subscript $tk$ indicates that $Z_0=tk$. When $n\to\infty$, $[Z_n=0]$ converges to $[\mbox{extinction}]$ and $q_n\to q=\mathrm P[\mbox{extinction}]$. Assume that $0<q<1$, that is, assume that $\mathrm E_1(Z_1)>1$ and $\mathrm P_1(Z_0=0)>0$. One would have
$$
\mathrm P_{tk}(\mbox{extinction},Z_1>k)\leqslant q^k\mathrm P_{tk}(\mbox{extinction})=q^{(t+1)k}.
$$
Using the fact that the event of extinction is the least probable when $Z_1$ is large and restricting the LHS to the event $[k<Z_1\le sk]$, one would have
$$
q^{sk}\mathrm P_{tk}(k<Z_1\le sk)\leqslant q^{(t+1)k}.
$$
Now, choose $s$ and $t$ such that $1<t\mathrm E_1(Z_1)<s$. Then $\mathrm P_{tk}(k<Z_1\le sk)\to1$ when $k\to\infty$ by the law of large numbers hence one would have $q^{s}\leqslant q^{t+1}$. If $s<t+1$, this is absurd and the condition that $1<t\mathrm E_1(Z_1)<s<t+1$ can be met for every $t$ such that $1/t$ is between $\mathrm E_1(Z_1)-1$ and $\mathrm E_1(Z_1)$.

Comment: Start with the equation $\mathbb{P}(Z_n=0, Z_m=j)=G_{n-m}(0)^j\, \mathbb{P}(Z_m=j)$, bound by $G_{n}(0)^{k+1}\, \mathbb{P}(Z_m=j)$, and add over $j>k$ to get $\mathbb{P}(Z_n=0, Z_m>k)\leq G_{n}(0)^{k+1}$. Dividing by $\mathbb{P}(Z_n=0)=G_n(0)$ gives the result, no matter what the initial conditions are.

Comment: @Byron, Except that your definition of $G_{n-m}$ is based on $Z_0=1$ the first time you use it (otherwise your first equality is false), but later on you write $P(Z_n=0)=G_n(0)$, which assumes that $G_n$ is based on $Z_0=i$. You cannot have it both ways...

Comment: Aha! You are quite right. My mistake.

Comment: @Didier: I didn't except the analysis of the impact of $Z_0$. But, it made me learn a lot. Thanks.

Comment: You are welcome. This part is less classical than the first one, as you can see from the much more gory details of the proof.